# How do I run a gui Java application headless, without control of the source code?

Tags: java, user-interface, command-line-interface

I want to execute a Jar file using javax swing GUI with 1 radial option, a file selector and a button. The goal is to be able to automate the jar through CLI and select the radial option, file and then click the button.

I do not have access to edit the source of the jar

Is this possible?

Comment: What do you mean with "through CLI"? Because any websearch for "run java on command line" will teach you about `java -jar yourfile.jar`

Comment: That would startup the jar file, but I would be unable to automatically select the options I want. The goal is to be able to select the radial option and file automatically without user interaction

Comment: okay, so then you need to change your description to mention you want to _automate_ interaction with your application. And web search for that term in relation to java applications, too.

Answer (score 1):

You can look up [JAuto](https://heshiming.github.io/jauto/), which is a [JVMTI](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/platform/jvmti/jvmti.html) agent that is capable of expose UI widget attributes such as class names, screen coordinates. You talk to JAuto by sending a command to a named pipe. It responds by writing a file. A communication scheme like this works in [bash scripts](https://heshiming.github.io/jauto/faq.html#how-do-i-call-jauto-in-a-bash-script).

With the help of [xdotool](https://github.com/jordansissel/xdotool) as an input simulator, you can achieve automation under the Linux X11 environment, inside a docker container.

Although depending on the complexity of the Java app, automating it in a headless manner can also be time-consuming. You may also need a VNC setup to inspect program behavior. Checkout this project [IBGA](https://heshiming.github.io/ibga/) and see how it uses JAuto and xdotool to automate a program.

Disclaimer: I'm the author of both JAuto and IBGA.